# Subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ arising as genera of smooth projective curves in a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Given a smooth projective variety, the genera of the smooth projective curves in it form a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Assuming the dimension is at least $2$, I think this subset is polynomially spaced, i.e., there is a non-constant polynomial $P$ such that there is an element between $P(n)$ and $P(n+1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

> **Question.** What polynomially spaced subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ do we get this way? Can we get cofinite proper subsets? Does the answer depend on the ground field?

Answer (score 5):

Let me give a partial answer about surfaces.

You can surely get the whole of $\mathbb{N}$, at least over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $Q = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, and let $L$, $M$ be the classes of the two rulings. Then, for $a, \, b >0$, the divisor $aL + bM$ is very ample, of genus $(a-1)(b-1)$.

In particular, the genus of $(n+1)L+2M$ is $n$.

I am not sure that it is possible to give a complete classification of all possible subsets that one obtains, since there in principle are a lot of different situations. Just to give an example, the subset $$\{n^2+1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$ is realized by a simple, principally polarized Abelian surface.

<strike>As another example, for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ you can realize a proper infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ containing the set $\{1, \ldots, N\}$ by considering suitably chosen nodal curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and blowing up the nodes.</strike>

Comment: Can't any projective curve be embedded into $\mathbf{P}^4$?

Comment: Is it always that the set obtained from blowing up a bunch of nodes in $\mathbb P^2$ is always a proper subset of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @YCor: yes. I wanted to show that one can obtain $\mathbb{N}$ also for surfaces, I edited the answer to explain this.

Comment: @WillSawin: well, in $\mathbb{P}^2$ there are infinitely many gaps for the genus. I do not see any obvious way of filling all these gaps just by blowing up a finite number of points.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi If you blow up two points on a line, then the surface is the blowup of $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ at a point, and one can take the strict transform of your examples in $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ to get curves in arbitrary genus.

Comment: @WillSawin: but you are now blowing up nodal curves, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by blowing up curves. We're taking $\mathbb P^2$, blowing up points, and looking for curves on it. One way of constructing the curves is by thinking about curves in $\mathbb P^2$ and their strict transform on the blow-up, but there are other ways. Regardless, as long as you blow up two distinct points, you will have smooth curves of all genera.

Comment: Right, I was only considering nodal curves and blowing up their nodes. Your construction works, of course.

Answer (score 0):

On a surface, the adjunction formula tells us that the genus of a smooth projective curve is a quadratic polynomial of the class of the curve. The class of the curve lies in $\mathbb Z^n$, $n$ the Picard rank of the surface, so the set of genera looks like the image of a polynomial map from $\mathbb Z^n$, except for the fact that not every class necessarily contains a smooth projective curve. (For negative classes, this is true for straightforward reasons, but there can be subtler obstructions as well.)

Francesco Polizzi gives a few examples where one knows exactly which classes contain smooth curves, and thus can give a precise description. Surely one can find more examples with a little effort, but a complete classification handling all surfaces seems elusive.